# Can't POST data to Laravel 5 controller using Angular, Error : 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I have a login form which uses `angularjs`. I want to send the entered credentials to default `AuthController` in **Laravel 5**. the problem I have is that server returns **422 Unprocessable Entity** and says in response : `email field is required`.

**HTML :**

```
<form class="login-form" ng-controller="LoginController" name="loginForm" novalidate>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" ng-model="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
    <h3 class="form-title">
Login
    </h3>
    <div ng-show="msg" class="alert alert-danger ng-cloak">
        <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
        <span ng-repeat="m in msgs">
        @{{m}}
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : loginForm.$submitted && loginForm.username.$error.required}">
        <!--ie8, ie9 does not support html5 placeholder, so we just show field title for that-->
        <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">
Username
        </label>
        <input ng-required="true" class="form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix ltr" type="text" autocomplete="off" ng-model="username" name="username"/>
    <span ng-show="loginForm.$submitted && loginForm.username.$error.required" class="help-block help-block-error ng-cloak">
Error Text
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"  ng-class="{'has-error' : loginForm.$submitted && loginForm.password.$error.required}">
        <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">
            Password
        </label>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="forget-password" class="forget-password">
            Text
        </a>

        <input ng-required="true" class="form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix ltr" type="password" autocomplete="off" ng-model="password" name="password"/>
    <span ng-show="loginForm.$submitted && loginForm.password.$error.required" class="help-block help-block-error ng-cloak">
            Text
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button  ng-click="login(loginForm.$valid,'.login-btn')" type="submit" data-loading-text="waiting" class="btn btn-success uppercase login-btn">ورود</button>
        <label class="rememberme check pull-right">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" ng-model="remember" value="1"/>
remember me
        </label>
    </div>

</form>
```

**JS Controller :**

```
this.msgs = '';
$scope.login = function (isValid, btn) {
    if(isValid) {
        $(btn).button('loading');

        $scope.msgs = '';

        data = {
            username : $scope.username,
            password : $scope.password,
            _token : $scope._token
        };

        if($scope.remember)
            data.remember = $scope.remember;

        $http.post('/auth/login', data)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $(btn).button('reset');
                $scope.msgs = '';
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $(btn).button('reset');
                // Handle login errors here
                $scope.msgs = data;
            });
    }
};
```

How to fix the issue with default laravel controller while using username as identification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to login with username instead of email, it should be as simple as setting the `username` property on your `AuthController` class

```
class AuthController extends Controller {
    protected $username = 'username';
}
```

The reason is that AuthController uses the [AuthenticatesUsers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php) trait, which checks if the `$username` property is set and if not, defaults to `'email'`

If you want them to have the option to login with username **or** email then that's another story. [I wrote a blog post about it](http://andrew.cool/blog/60/Login-with-username-or-email).

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, 422 error message is a semantic error.

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
>   understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
>   415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
>   syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
>   status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
>   instructions. For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
>   request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
>   semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

And in Laravel documentation, it says the by default, the email field is used as the "username":

> By default, the auth.basic middleware will use the email column on the
>   user record as the "username".

I suggest you to edit the auth.basic parameter in middleware config in order to use "username" as the main username.

Comment: Its not using a middleware, its requesting `/auth/login` for authentication(cookie setting). I think it has nothing to do with middlewares

Comment: Did you attach middleware to your login route ? By default, it's attached to: Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'auth.basic', function() {

Comment: I have searched google for a Laravel 5 example but got no luck, if you provide one I'll figure it out. :)

Comment: Documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication and then, try this one: https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-and-angularjs-token-based-auth-part1/

Comment: He's using this method in order to restrict it to the email (or not): $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

Answer (score -1):

Because you're passing only the *username* and *password* (and remember) fields.
You probably need for an email key in the data object!

```
var data = { email: 'superman@gmail.com', username: 'SuperMan', password: 'ASDASD', rememberMe: true};
```